# Change date from active to inactive

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I want to change an active date <2017-12-10 17:04> to inactive date [2017-12-10 17:04] and vice versa.

How do I do that?

Comment: The opposite of "active" is "inactive".  Using the word "passive" in the question and in the answer makes it less likely that someone can find this thread in the future using Google or other search engine.  See the org-mode manual for the correct terminology:  http://orgmode.org/guide/Creating-timestamps.html

Comment: @lawlist: I edited the question.

Comment: @lawlist I am editing the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @FrancescoTurco Thanks! That was perfect.

Comment: @lawlist FYI regarding the word "passive": not everyone is a native english speaker. In some languages, the opposite of "active" is "passive". So it is valid to mention that word along with "inactive". :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR;
From the keyboard (in org-mode):

```
C-c .
```

to activate (convert from inactive to active).

```
C-c !
```

to inactivate (convert from active to inactive).

From lisp:

```
(org-time-stamp t)
```

to activate, and

```
(org-time-stamp t t)
```

to inactivate.

Edit: As Juancho points out, `<S-up>` and `<S-down>` both toggle between active and inactive timestamps.

Comment: You can also use shift UP/DOWN when the cursor is on the opening or closing brackets.